Does this Lime Tree need pruning?
I just bought this air layered lime tree on sale at a garden center. Its main stem has grown sideways so I was wondering if it needs pruning, and where do I need to cut it to make it grow straight and become more stable.
It will also soon need a bigger pot, it was recommended by the garden center that I use cactus soil. I usually mix my cactus soil with 1:1:1 potting soil, perlite and sharp sand.
I live in the tropics so the tree will be outside year round. Will this soil mix work? It can get really hot so I want well draining soil, but it shouldn't dry out too quickly.
I saw suggestions of using a 5:1:1 mix with pine bark, but not sure how easy it is to get that here. I do however have a bag of bromeliad mix I can use instead of pine.
Thanks for your suggestions!

Pruning
See if you like this idea of shortening the highest and widest branches:

Soil
For soil mix, you want a light loam that drains easily. But other than clay, citrus grows in many soils in China, the Mediterranean, Florida, and California.
Repotting
It won't hurt to wait on potting up a size or two, so the plant acclimates as is to its new environment, for sun, humidity, and such.
However, there are advantages to repotting and pruning around the same time, since nature would appreciate supporting fewer leaves when the plant inevitably loses some roots as you transplant. Nursery pots are by definition rootbound and in need of spaghetti-root pruning.
